# CSS horizontal scrolling issue

Tags: css

I have some weird CSS issue that I’m having the worst time locating. Something on the page (or in the css) is causing the page to allow for horizontal scrolling. I’ve tried pulling off individual sections of the site and it’s always there. Any ideas what it is?

here is a link to the dev http://phiaconcepts.devlocation.site

Comment: Some elements (e.g. the `<footer>` children) have a negative margin which is moving them outside of the parent.

Comment: And judging from your past questions, you should really read and adopt https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your problem is with the overflow property.
Add this property to the body tag:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

For more info look at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because something on your page is wider than the screen width. I would go through different larger HTML elements on the page and see which one solves the issue when deleted. When located, you will want to check the width of the parent and its children, especially checking for margins and padding that might make it too large.

[`box-sizing: border-box`] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) might be useful to keep the children in the parent container.

Adding `overflow-x: hidden` to one of the parent containers will also give a hacky fix, but that will be hiding part of the design.